# AP Computer Science: When member functions can run

Tags: java

So I'm given the following piece of code, and I'm supposed to find which cases the code will compile:

```
VariableType var = new ObjectType();
var.doStuff();
```

This code is guaranteed to compile if (select all that apply):

- doStuff() is a member function of VariableType
- doStuff() is a member function of ObjectType
- doStuff() is a member function of VariableType's superclass
- doStuff() is a member function of ObjectType's superclass

The only one I marked was the second one, although I'm really not sure whether the other cases do work also. There also isn't an answer to the problem, and I'm somewhat stumped. So if any one of you guys could explain each of the cases and why they work or don't work, that would help a lot.

Comment: If you're *calling* it on a variable of type VariableType, then the method has to be *declared* in VariableType, a superclass that it extends, or an interface it implements.

Comment: Try creating the classes VariableType and ObjectType, then implement doStuff() in either class according to the definitions of the question and see if they compile. That's how I would figure out what works/doesn't. Then you can research further from there.

Comment: The question is about when *calls* to member functions will *compile*. Not when they can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there some unstated requirements.  For this statement to compile:

```
VariableType var = new ObjectType();
```

1. `ObjectType` must be a non-abstract class with a suitable constructor,
2. `VariableType` must be a class or interface, and
3. `ObjectType` must be a direct or indirect subtype of `VariableType`.

If any of those requirements is not met, then the above statement will not compile.

Now for the meat of your question.

> [This code is guaranteed to compile] if doStuff() is a member function of VariableType

True.  The compiler checks that the method is present in the API provided by `VariableType`.  It is.

> [This code is guaranteed to compile] if doStuff() is a member function of ObjectType

False.  In the case where `doStuff()` is defined in `ObjectType` but not in `VariableType`, the call will not compile.

While the method would be present at runtime in this example, the compiler requires that the method call will work for all possible values that could be assigned to `var`.  Some possible values could be instances of `VariableType` itself, or some other subclass of `VariableType`

> [This code is guaranteed to compile] if doStuff() is a member function of VariableType's superclass

True.  When `doStuff()` is defined in `VariableType`'s superclass, then it is inherited by `VariableType`, and part of that classes API.

> [This code is guaranteed to compile] if doStuff() is a member function of ObjectType's superclass

False. Consider the case where `ObjectType` extends `A` and `A` extends `VariableType`, and `VariableType` does not define a `doStuff` method.

In this scenario, it makes no difference that `A` has a `doStuff()` method.  That method is not exposed via the `VariableType` API, and therefore can't be called like that.

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler sees a method call, it only cares about the *declared* type of the variable or expression that the method is called on. In this case, the variable is `var`, and its declared type is `VariableType`. Therefore, only methods declared in `VariableType` or its supertypes may be called.

Note, that the assignment `VariableType var = new ObjectType();` only compiles if `ObjectType` is a subclass of `VariableType`, so I guess we're supposed to assume that that is the case. That doesn't change the answer, though - methods declared in `ObjectType` are not "visible through" `VariableType`. Even if a method is declared in a superclass of `ObjectType`, it could be that that superclass is still a subclass of `VariableType` - for example, if you have `class FooType extends VariableType` and `class ObjectType extends FooType`.

The purpose of all of this is to ensure that a call that compiles is guaranteed to succeed at runtime. If we allowed `var.methodThatOnlyExistsInObjectType()` to compile, it would fail at runtime if `var` didn't actually refer to an `ObjectType`.